# linux32 and installation Oxford Advanced Learner

Tags: gtk, theme

I try to install `oal8`, on Debian 64bit, And I insatlled the overall *:i386 packages on my machine and I solved my problems....
But I don't understand the following error:

```
# linux32 ./oald8

(oald8-bin:28333): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "adwaita",

(oald8-bin:28333): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "adwaita",
```

Question is , What's above message?

Comment: Seems the Adwaita theme is a dependency...

Comment: I remember to I don't need same thing on i386 machine...Do you have any suggesstion?

Comment: Install it and see if it stops complaining.

Answer (score -1):

You have to rename /usr/share/themes/Adwaita/ to /usr/share/themes/adwaita/
Uppercase to lowercaser

Comment: Why? The theme installs itself as `/usr/share/themes/Adwaita`, and that is the proper name. You might end up breaking other applications. Use a symlink instead.